# Setting null without getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

```
if (request.getHeight() != null) {
   mechEquipment.setHeight(request.getHeight());
}

if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(request.getCargoBoxSize())) {
   mechEquipment.setCargoBoxSize(request.getCargoBoxSize());
}
```

I use clauses like these to set my data, but sometimes I need to set it to null. If I remove the if clause, and I haven't changed the item, it gives me a null pointer exception, because it isn't in the PATCH request.

How can I change this?

Currently I have weight set at let's say 300. If I clear the input on front end and send it, the request will be `weight = null`. But since the IF clause avoids that, I don't know what to do.

Comment: "I use clauses like these to set my data, but sometimes I need to set it to null. If I remove the if clause, and I haven't changed the item, it gives me a null pointer exception, because it isn't in the PUT request." - yeah, if your code depends on the values being != null it is a fault that they can be set to null in a request. Or your code makes wrong assumptions and the values can be null but then you have to remove the if-clause.

Comment: What is `mechEquipment` ? Is it a database model class?

Comment: If setting a null is ok for your logic, may be u just need 
`if (request != null) {
   mechEquipment.setHeight(request.getHeight());
}` ?

Comment: mechEquipment is a spring entity, yes.

Comment: Well, that would depend on what you want to do. Would you want to distinguish between the request containing `weight=xxx` and not containing `weight` at all, i.e. is it a difference whether that parameter is actually present or not? `request.getHeight()` etc. indicates that `request` isn't a servlet request but some pojo that has been created from the request parameters - in that case you'd need a special value to distinguish between "parameter not present" (`null`) and "delete the value" (special value).

Comment: The semantics of a PUT request is a replace - when your weight is not included a client might assume that it is now `null` and not "unchanged" - you mix PATCH and PUT semantics here.

Comment: @Smutje my bad, I meant to write PATCH request and that is what i'm using. If the request sent by the client doesn't contain weight, lenght, height or etc, they should stay the same. If the request contains height = null, 0 or what ever value, it should be changed.

Comment: Either distinguish between "weight absent" and "weight null", invent a "magic constant" for a reset or allow "empty" instead of "null".

Comment: @AbbinVarghese using this I run into a problem where if I have height, length, weigth and I only change height- the height value becomes as sent by the client, but length and weight become 0 because the request doesn't contain them.

Comment: You need to fetch the object from the DB, then change it where the request indicates it and merge the changes.

Comment: 'How can I change this?' Err, don't remove the `if` clause? If you set things to null you have to test them before dereferencing them. Unclear what you're really asking here.

Comment: @HeikoPiirme what is the data type of setCargoBoxSize and setHeight if it is int then its due to autoboxing and unboxing refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html .please change it to Integer  wrapperdata type it will not throw null pointer exception

Comment: @ManojKrishna I'm using BigInteger currently

Comment: @HeikoPiirme please post the stack trace so we can have an idea where it is throwing null pointer exactly

Answer (score 0):

When you work with POJOs you have no indication of whether the field was sent as null or was not sent.

If you need this indication and would like to implement a PATCH endpoint, you will probably need to either work with JSON objects (where you can check if the key exists or not).

Another option is to serialize from JSON to POJO and including a boolean indication for each field, or to include a set of field names that were included in the request as part of the POJO, but you will need to do some work in order on the deserializer to have this behavior (unless there is a library that handles that already, I didn't see anything like that)

Answer (score 0):

Java-8 offers [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class : The purpose of the class is to provide a type-level solution for representing optional values along with null values instead of null references.

> *Currently I have weight set at let's say 300. If I clear the input on front end and send it, the request will be `weight = null`. But since
>   the IF clause avoids that, I don't know what to do.*

You can create the *weight* like:

```
Optional<Integer> weight = Optional.ofNullable(null); //can take weight as null also
Optional<Integer> weight = Optional.of(100); // will take any values except null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper object in your request, although it's not very clean.

```
{
    "height":{ "value": null },
    "width":{ "value": 500 },
}
```

This way you can check if the whole `Height` or `Width` object exists, and if it does, you apply its `value` irrespective of it being null or not.

Personally I'd rather keep the request body clean and do what Eyal suggested in his answer instead, but this may be an easier solution to implement.

Comment: if `height` is null, is there any need of `width`?

Comment: @VishwaRatna Well it was just a dumb example, imagine that instead of width you have any other property that is independent of height and you want to set to a valid value.

Answer (score -1):

> You can use conditional ternary operator like

```
 mechEquipment.setHeight(request == null ? null : request.getHeight());
```

> It will check if request null then set null otherwise output of getter method

Comment: But if I don't change Height, instead I change Width for example. The request will not be null, but request.getHeight() will be. That means when I only change Width- height, length, weight and others will become null.

Comment: May be argument type is premitive `mechEquipment.setHeight(int heignt)` change to object type `mechEquipment.setHeight(Integer heignt)` and remove not null,
Because on unwrap from object Integer->int if source value null then it gives NullPointerException